# オブジェクトのキーを検索して、値を設定する

Tags: javascript

初めて質問させていただきます。

```
const state = {
      item: [
        {
          a: '',
          b: '',
          c: '',
          parts: [
            {
              x: '',
              y: '',
              z: ''
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

上記のようなオブジェクトから指定のキーを検索して、その値を設定したいと考えています。

```
function searchObj (obj, query) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key]
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      searchObj(value, query)
    }
    if (key === query) {
      return obj[key]
    }
  }
}
```

関数を設定して、返り値でもらったプロパティキーの値を設定するようにしました。

```
var key = searchObj(state.item[0], 'x'))
key = 'value'
```

この場合、'x'の値に'value'が入って欲しいのですが、どうしてもsearchObjの返り値が分からず質問させていただきました。
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 再帰的に呼び出そうとしている`serachObj(value, query)`で値が見つかった場合に`return`で値を返さないとそのまま処理を抜けてしまいませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず、再帰的に呼び出すなら再帰呼び出しの結果を返さないと。あと `item` や `parts` にもマッチさせるなら、`key === query` は先に書いた方が速いです。

```
function searchObj (obj, query) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (key === query) {
      return obj[key];
    }
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      let result = searchObj(value, query);
      if (result !== undefined) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

これで検索はできますが、Javascriptでは**変数への参照やポインタを返すことはできません**。代入演算子の挙動を変えるような方法もありません。ですから、

```
var key = searchObj(state.item[0], 'x'))
key = 'value'
```

これをそのまま実現することは不可能です。

代わりの策を考えるとしたら、発見したプロパティに値を設定する関数を返すとか

```
function searchObj (obj, query) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (key === query) {
      return function(val){ obj[key] = val; };
    }
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      let result = searchObj(value, query);
      if (result !== undefined) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

var setter = searchObj(state.item[0], 'x'));
setter('value');
```

発見したプロパティを含むオブジェクトを返すとか

```
function searchObj (obj, query) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    if (key === query) {
      return obj;
    }
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      let result = searchObj(value, query);
      if (result !== undefined) {
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

var parent = searchObj(state.item[0], 'x'));
parent.x = 'value';
```

というところでしょうか。

Comment: 両方ともに実現できました！ありがとうございました。